# How to find the center manifold for the following system

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems

Consider the following system
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= -2x - y - xy\\
\dot{y} &= 2x + y + 2xy
\end{align*}
I am trying to determine its center manifold around point $(0,0)$.

I tried to use the approximation $h(x) = ax^2 + bx^3 + \cdots$, however, there will be an $\mathcal{O}(x)$ term in the center manifold formula. I also tried to directly solve $y$ for $x$ by considering $dy/dx$, but the integrand is way too complicated and I didn't see a way to solve it.

So could any one give me some hints?

**Trial 1**
The linearized system at $(0,0)$ has matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1 \\
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
and the eigenvectors are
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}\;,
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then the transformation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1\\-1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which gives the transformed system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{u} \\ \dot{v}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\dot{x} - \dot{y} \\ -\dot{x} - \dot{y}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2x+y \\ -xy
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Plugging in $(x,y) = (-u-v,u-2v)$ gives
\begin{align*}
\dot{u} &= -u \\
\dot{v} &= 2v^2 - 3uv + u^2
\end{align*}

Comment: First you need to transform your ODEs to a system that has a center manifold of the form $v = h(u)$. Apply the substitution $(x, y) = (-u - v, 2 u + v)$ (the coefficients are the components of eigenvectors of the linearized system). You should obtain $(\dot u, \dot v) = (f(u, v), -v)$, for which a center manifold can be found in closed form.

Comment: @Maxim I tried your way and I added to the post above. But I end up with a different result as yours. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Your result is also fine, but, according to the theorem about the existence of a CM of the form $y = h(x)$ with $h(0) = h'(0) = 0$, your system has a CM of the form $u = h(v)$, not $v = h(u)$. Now you can differentiate $u = h(v)$ to obtain
$$-h(v) = h'(v) (2 v^2 - 3 v h(v) + h^2(v))$$
and then find a power series solution, but you'll quickly notice that if the lowest power of $v$ on the lhs is $2$, then the lowest power on the rhs is $3$, and so on.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, I see this as well. So how can I determine the coefficients?

Comment: $h(v) = 0$ is a solution :). You can directly verify that $u = 0$ satisfies the requirements for a CM: it is an invariant manifold because the first equation is $\dot u = -u$, and $h(0) = h'(0) = 0$.